# RDLC Edit Existing Dataset is blank in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, rdlc

Hi I was wondering if someone could help, after having to replace my hard disk and re-installing windows and vs 2013. I can get my project working which is great. However when I try to edit an existing rdlc datset it is blank? this is also the case if I create a new dataset on the report, it doesn't even store the name I type it just states Dataset1

I have tried rebuilding and cleaning the solution but to no avail

Thanks in advance

Comment: Help me if you can...

Comment: I have still this issue left